# Databricks Committed_vacuum in AWS S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I have a job on Spark 3.0 on Databricks running on a daily basis. I'm writing data every data on a S3 partition folder using overwrite. It was everything fine until this morning. I've checked my S3 and noticed a `committed_vacuum` in my daily partition. Does anyone know what this actually means?

Answer (score 0):

According to Databricks documentation that you can see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/dbio-commit.html#clean-up-uncommitted-files) sounds to me that this partition or there was a failure and the files were not proper committed to S3. This is one of the tools provided by Databricks with the capabilities taken from the Delta Lake project that allows concurrent writes.

So your job probably had a failure, or the commit didn't happened properly and this `committed_vacuum` is a result of an uncommitted data.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nvwJ.png)

Not sure. I'm not using Delta. Although I'm using spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")

Comment: You can see the attached picture with my vacuum file on S3.